# Using Pandas dataframe to group data by dates and then hours

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

I am working with a pandas dataframe where I would like to group the first five days and last five days together. Then from that grouping, I'd like to average the sample measurement from the same hour. ie: Of those 10 days, sample measurements from 00:00:00 averaged. Any guidance on how to achieve this would be much appreciated. Thank you.

| Datetime | Sample Measurement |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-08-17 00:00:00 | 10 |
| 2019-08-17 01:00:00 | 14 |
| 2019-08-17 02:00:00 | 12 |
| 2019-08-17 03:00:00 | 10 |
| ..... | .... |
| 2019-09-07 20:00:00 | 9 |
| 2019-09-07 21:00:00 | 7 |
| 2019-09-07 22:00:00 | 5 |
| 2019-09-07 23:00:00 | 3 |

Comment: Please paste how your DataFrame is created, or at least a code sample that can help us reproduce how your dataframe is behaving

Comment: The dataframe is just a straightforward CSV file being read in- basically a large excel spreadsheet. Only manipulation up to this point has been quality control. I'm not sure if that helps.

Comment: i was asking because there are lots of ways to store a date/time. If you could post a minimal reproducible example and the expected output it would be great.

Comment: I understand now-- sorry about that. Yes, the data initially had the date and time separated, but I joined and use them as an index. I

df2.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df2['Date Local'] + ' ' + df2['Time Local']), inplace=True)

Comment: Keep the date and time in separated columns, collect and sort all the different days you have, select the first 5 and last 5, filter you dataframe on these days. Then group by the time column and compute the mean.

Answer (score 2):

First you will need to change the DateTime column to date time object using [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) method

then make a new column with date only for example:

```
 df['date_only'] = df['Datetime'].dt.date
```

would work in your case

then use pandas groupby and mean methods to group all similar dates together and then take the mean of their sample measurement

for ex:

```
df.groupby(['date_only'])['Sample Measurement'].mean()
```

would work